# constructing a parse tree/ AST from java byte code

Tags: java, parsing, programming-languages, bytecode

are there any ways or libraries available that can be used to build a parse tree from java byte code? My actual goal is to create an AST. I know there are libraries available for building AST from source codes, just want to know ways to build the AST from byte code only.

Comment: Isn't byte-code a form of assembly? A syntax tree of that would either be one long linked-list of instructions or you'd need to reverse-compile the bytecode.

Comment: A plugin for eclipse: [Flowchart4j](http://www.codeswat.com/cswat/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=34&Itemid=55)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You no longer have a syntax tree once it's compiled down to bytecode.  If you're trying to build a Java syntax tree out of bytecode, then you're really trying to write a decompiler.

(Bytecode itself isn't so much a tree as just a sequence of instructions; it's not really tree-shaped in the way that you'd expect an AST to be.)